# Mavic 2 Pro - File system access

Tags: dji-sdk

I am accessing the drone FS via ftp://192.168.42.2/
HOWEVER, when trying to eg. delete log files, I get ftp error "Invalid Command DELE"

Is there any way to access the Drone Internal FS?
Should I need a dev account for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't

DJI have done a good job to secure everything on that filesystem. Mainly due to "no flight zones database".

Comment: Is there a long answer?
I read that DJI FS can be accessed using ADB...

Comment: You can get a adb root shell on one of the earlier firmware. Most firmware cannot be downgraded. Easiest way is to buy hacking software that gives you the root shell.